# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

iam receving this error, `htmlentities()` expects parameter 1 to be string, object given. How to solve it?
My controller

```
public function category()
    {
      $recordsByCategories=\DB::table('products')
                 ->select('categories', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('categories')
                 ->get();


     //dd($recordsByCategories);
     return view('dashboard.show',compact('recordsByCategories'));

    }
```

my view

```
@foreach($recordsByCategories as $recordsByCategory)
{!!$recordsByCategory->$categories!!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the dd - the data structure returned by get() is not an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

try this in view

use `{{$recordsByCategory->categories}}` instead of `{{$recordsByCategory}}`

It is because `$recordsByCategory` is an object

One another problem here is, when you use `count(*)` in this query then it will return only one row in result.

Answer (score 0):

`$recordsByCategory` is an object, not a string, so `{{$recordsByCategory}}` makes no sense. You want to display properties of the record, not the entire record itself.